# Shouldn't Google Compute Engine disk auto-resize when uploading data?

Tags: partition, google-compute-engine

> ... automatic disk resizing during boot time...
>   All Compute Engine Ubuntu images will automatically resize the root partition to use the entire disk, up to a 2 TB limit. Even if the disk is larger than 2 TB, the operating system only recognizes up to 2 TB.

According to Google's [Persistent Disk documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks), Ubuntu should auto-resize, but when I tried to upload 20GB data (contains small files):

```
"No space left on device"
```

I'm using gcloud:

```
gcloud compute copy-files ...
```

to upload the files.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.9G  9.8G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           371M  536K  370M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ea22e

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 20971519 20969472  10G 83 Linux
```

Comment: You should try asking this on Server Fault. Still, to me, sounds like what you quoted should be taken to mean "will partition the whole disk upon creation."

Comment: can I move it somehow to Server Fault?

Comment: You have to request/vote for it to be moved. It's in the flag option, and I'm trying to initiate the process myself, but I can't seem to select Server Fault as the correct site.

Comment: OK, I marked it to be moved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out:

> All Compute Engine Ubuntu images will automatically **resize the root
>   partition to use the entire disk**

Then, as per your output, you have a 10GB disk and a 10GB partition so it's not possible to resize that partition.

If you want to have a larger root disk, you'll need to create disk with the desired space. You can do it with the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) with the following steps:

1- Create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot) of your instance:

`gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK_NAME --snapshot-names SNAPSHOT_NAME --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

2- Create a [disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) based on that snapshot:

`gcloud compute disks create NAME --source-snapshot SOURCE_SNAPSHOT --size SIZE --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

After that the disk is automatically partitioned with enough space for the root filesystem

3- Create an [instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) with that disk:

`gcloud compute instances create NAME --disk "name=DISK_NAME" "boot=yes" --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

Since Ubuntu supports automatic resizing, once it boots it should resize the partition and you should have the desired GB.

**Alternatively**, if you are still able to SSH into the instance, you can attach a new disk to the instance following these steps:

4- Create a [new disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create):
`gcloud compute disks create NAME --size SIZE --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

5- [Attach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) the new disk:
`gcloud compute instances attach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk NEW_DISK_NAME --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

6- [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) into the instance:
`gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME --zone ZONE --project PROJECT_ID`

7- [Format](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting) the new disk.

8- Transfer files from the root disk to the new one to free up space and upload the other files to the new disk.

Comment: thank you. What I did is to create new disc and after from the instance options page to attach it. Then this disc should be formated and mounted from the ubuntu terminal. I used this command to do this : sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_disk-1 /var/www   (Is it possible to create snapshot from these two discs and to make only one?)

Comment: I have updated my answer to take into account your solution. Regarding your other question, unfortunately, you need to make a snapshot for each disk.