# How to resize a root persistent disk of a Drupal/Debian instance on Google Compute Engine

Tags: partition, drupal, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

It's about a Drupal 7 site running on a debian 7 virtual machine instance on Google Compute Engine, deployed by [this tutoriel](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/drupal/click-to-deploy)

Actually noting is running because boot/root disk full, MySQL crash ...

```
root@drpl-gce:/# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  9.9G  9.7G     0 100% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   372M  148K  372M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac75b061-bf43-4298-9234-8a555ab0f9ac  9.9G  9.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   743M     0  743M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb                                                 99G  324M   94G   1% /drupal
tmpfs                                                   743M   69M  675M  10% /tmp
```

I follow [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/683602/shouldnt-google-compute-engine-disk-auto-resize-when-uploading-data/683603#683603) with snapshots for both disks, but I lose the drupal dependence in the new instance.

```
root@drpl-gce-ext:/# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   50G  5.0G   42G  11% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   372M  152K  372M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac75b061-bf43-4298-9234-8a555ab0f9ac   50G  5.0G   42G  11% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   743M     0  743M   0% /run/shm
tmpfs                                                   743M  4.0K  743M   1% /tmp
```

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean that you lose the Drupal dependency? When you boot with the resized disks Drupal no longer runs?

Comment: Also, which approach from the tutorial did you use? Did you make a new root disk from a snapshot of your initial (full) root disk?

Comment: It's like the other partition (100G) with the drupal folder isn't no longuer the www folder for the server.

Comment: Yes, but strangely it is no longer the same space used on the new instance

Comment: Can you still mount the original disk? If so, just copy the Drupal folder over.

Comment: OK, can you edit you post to show the exact steps which you did?

Comment: Since you've already created a snapshot of your root disk, your deployment and data should be safe. Try going through the first method mentioned in this solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/683602/shouldnt-google-compute-engine-disk-auto-resize-when-uploading-data/683603#683603

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by making two correct snapshots for both disks, and attach them to a new instance, one(root disk)  as a boot disk, the other (Drupal files) as aditional disk, like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/683602/shouldnt-google-compute-engine-disk-auto-resize-when-uploading-data/683603#683603)

```
root@drpl-gce-ext:/# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   50G  9.9G   37G  22% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   372M  144K  372M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac75b061-bf43-4298-9234-8a555ab0f9ac   50G  9.9G   37G  22% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   743M     0  743M   0% /run/shm
tmpfs                                                   743M   16K  743M   1% /tmp
```

According to [this google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#create_disk), additional disks are not mounted or formatted when they are first created and/or attached.
So first, I have to verify if disk is correctly attached, and mount it on drupal folder

```
root@drpl-gce-ext:/#ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/google-*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0  9 Aug  6 09:55 /dev/disk/by-id/google-drpl-gctm-data-ext -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0  9 Aug  6 09:55 /dev/disk/by-id/google-drpl-gctm-ma0l-ext -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 10 Aug  6 09:55 /dev/disk/by-id/google-drpl-gctm-ma0l-ext-part1 -> ../../sda1

root@drpl-gce-ext:/#mount -a /dev/sdb /drupal

root@drpl-gce-ext:/# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   50G  9.9G   37G  22% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   372M  144K  372M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac75b061-bf43-4298-9234-8a555ab0f9ac   50G  9.9G   37G  22% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   743M     0  743M   0% /run/shm
tmpfs                                                   743M   16K  743M   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb                                                 99G  324M   94G   1% /drupal
```

Now it works fine !